# Print message in the middle of long pipe

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe, tidyverse, magrittr

In my R script, I would like to print a message in the middle of a long pipe (which takes a long time to run) without breaking the pipe. I need this to track the progress of the running pipeline.

I tried to create a simple function that prints a message without breaking the pipe:

```r
CatPipe <- function(x, message = NULL) {
  cat(message, sep = "\n")
  return(x)
}
```

Here is an example implementation:

```
require(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
  CatPipe("Hello1") %>% 
  {
    Sys.sleep(1)
    .
  } %>% 
  CatPipe("Hello2") %>% 
  {
    Sys.sleep(1)
    .
     } %>% 
    head(5) %>% 
    CatPipe("Hello3")
```

However, the printed messages were not as expected. The messages are printed in reverse order, irrespective if the current step was finished or not!

```
Hello3
Hello2
Hello1
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

Is there an explanation for this? Should I make any changes to the function? Is there an alternative for this using `dplyr`, `magrittr`, or similar packages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `%>%` pipe uses **lazy evaluation**, which means that it doesn't evaluate expressions until it needs to. In practice, this means that it reaches the *end* of the pipe and then works backward ... the `magrittr` package defines an **eager pipe** operator `%!>%` which has the behaviour you want (`%>%` actually comes from `magrittr` as well; it's imported and re-exported by `dplyr`).

In order to print the `mtcars` output before `Hello3`, you can use a **tee pipe** (`%T>%`), also from `magrittr`, plus a `print()` statement. The reason the output usually prints at the end is that R only prints the final result of an expression once it has been completely evaluated. (I also added a `-> result` to the end of the pipe to store the result and prevent it from being printed again at the end; I added a `SleepPipe()` function similar to  your `CatPipe()` to make the code a little bit prettier.)

```r
library(magrittr)
SleepPipe <- function(x, time = 1) {
    Sys.sleep(time)
    return(x)
}
mtcars %!>% 
  CatPipe("Hello1") %!>% 
  SleepPipe(1) %!>% 
  CatPipe("Hello2") %!>% 
  SleepPipe(1) %!>%
  head(5) %T>% print() %!>% 
  CatPipe("Hello3") -> result
```

- I can't guarantee that changing from lazy to eager evaluation won't have other side effects in a complicated pipeline
- the native-R pipe `|>` also uses lazy evaluation (to test it I had to use the `SleepPipe()` function, since the native pipe doesn't allow arbitrary `{.}` expressions)
- FWIW [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/pipes.html) contradicts this answer: it says that functions that use lazy evaluation won't work in piped workflows because "The pipe computes each element in turn, so you can’t rely on this behaviour". I think this is because `magrittr` [re-implemented the pipe to use lazy evaluation in version 2.0](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/news/news.html) ....

Comment: I did not know that an eager pipe exists. Thanks Ben. I read more on this here: https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/pipe-eager.html. I tried using `force(x)` in the function but this did not work. It shows all messages together after the end of the pipe.